# I am having troubles writing a test driver

Tags: java, testing, compiler-errors

my first time reaching out for help to solve a question, not sure what is causing the issue. I have these two classes I wrote, and the assignment asks me to make a test driver proving that the classes work.

Student Class:

```
public class Student{
    private Course[] courseList;
    private static int numCourses;
    private final int maxCourses;

public Student(int max){
    maxCourses = max;
    courseList = new Course[numCourses];
    numCourses = 0;
}
// part 1, done
public boolean addCourse(Course newClass){
    boolean success = false;

for(int i=0; i<=maxCourses; i++){

    if(i == numCourses){
    courseList[i] = newClass;
    success = true;
    numCourses++;
    }
}
return success;
}
// part 2, done
public boolean dropCourse(Course oldClass){
    boolean success = false;

for(int i=0; i<=courseList.length; i++){
    if (courseList[i] == oldClass){
        courseList[i] = null;
        numCourses--;
        success = true;
    }
}
return success;
}
// part 3, done.
    public int getNumCourses(){
    return numCourses;
    }
//part 4, done
    public boolean isFullTime(){
        boolean success = false;
        if (numCourses >= 3){
            success = true;
        }
        return success;
    }
// part 5, done
    public String getClassList(){
        String list = "";

    for(int i=0;i<=numCourses; i++){
        list = courseList[i].getID() + "\t" + courseList[i].getName() + "\n";

    }
    return list;
    }
}
```

and a Course class:

```
public class Course{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private static int nextID = 200000;

    public Course(String nameIn)
    {
    name = nameIn;
    id = nextID;
    nextID++;
    }
public String getName(){
return name;
}
public int getID(){
return id;
}
}
```

For some reason if I make a test driver even one as simple as:

```
public class tester{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Course one = new Course(Java);
}
}
```

I receive an error at my parameter saying cannot find symbol

```
javac tester.java
tester.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        one = new Course(name);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: class tester
1 error
```

I had a much longer test driver but it did not make it past the first few lines as this was the same error just several of the same error.

Thanks for your time.
EDIT: I had put the Student class in twice by mistake, in my short test driver the only class in use is the Course class.

Comment: You posted the Student class twice when you meant to post Course class

Comment: Also, if the constructor is an expecting a value from an enum that contains a list of possible courses, you would have to reference it as CourseEnum.Java

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I ended up having to leave for class but the constructor for the Course object takes in just 1 parameter (String name) but when creating the object in the test driver it does not accept the string i put in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that because there are not quotes around Java, the compiler takes it as a variable name. Since it is undefined, the compiler cant find it. Use `Course one = new Course("Java");`

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple mistake. I am still a rookie when it comes to programming and the month off for the holidays apparently made me forget the essentials.